# Parse multiline fasta file using record.id for filenames but not in headers

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, split, biopython, fasta

My current multiline fasta file is as such:

```
>chr1|chromosome:Mt4.0v2:1:1:52991155:1
ATGC...

>chr2|chromosome:Mt4.0v2:2:1:45729672:1
ATGC...
```

...and so on.

I need to parse the fasta file into separate files containing only the record.description in the header (everything after the |) followed by the sequence. However, I need to use the record.ids as the filenames (chr1.fasta, chr2.fasta, etc.). Is there any way to do this?

My current attempt at solving this is below. It does produce only the description in the header with the last sequence record.id as the filename.  I need seperate files.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def yield_records(in_file):
    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta'):
        record.description = record.id = record.id.split('|')[1]
        yield record

SeqIO.write(yield_records('/correctedfasta.fasta'), record.id+'.fasta', 'fasta')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has almost everything which is needed. `yield` can also return more than one value, i.e. you could return both the filename and the record itself, e.g.

```
yield record.id.split('|')[0], record
```

but then BioPython would still bite you because the `id` gets written to the FASTA header. You would therefore need to modify both the `id` and overwrite the `description` (it gets concatenated to the `id` otherwise), or just assign identical values as you did.

A simple solution would be

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def split_record(record):
    old_id = record.id.split('|')[0]
    record.id = '|'.join(record.id.split('|')[1:])
    record.description = ''
    return old_id, record

filename = 'multiline.fa'

for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, 'fasta'):
    record = split_record(record)
    with open(record[0] + '.fa', 'w') as f:
        SeqIO.write(record[1], f, 'fasta')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I also appreciate the explanation as to why my code wasn't working before. Thanks so much!